# linux file attributes

Tags: linux, file, system-calls

Use open syscall to write and create a file ,there's no attributes with the file. fedora16 gcc-4.6.3

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char *  str= "helloworld";
    int fd = open("test.db",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND);

    write(fd,str,10);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

ll test.db

> ----------. 1 jiamo jiamo 14 Apr 17 11:34 test.db

While it don't create file with the default file attributes such like `touch test.db`

umask : 0002

if drop the O_TRUNC
`int fd = open("test1.db",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND)`
the file attributs is :

> ----rwx---. 1 jiamo jiamo   14 Apr 17 12:29 test1.db

Comment: what's your umask in your shell?

Comment: umask 0002 (I have update the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the required permissions to the open() syscall:

```
int fd = open("test.db",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, 0666);
```

From the documentation:

```
mode must be specified when O_CREAT is in the flags, and is ignored otherwise.
The argument mode specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is created.
```

Comment: Worth describing: 0666 is usually the right third argument value, because one is usually creating a data file whose rights should be "read and write for everyone, minus any rights taken away by the user's umask".  For some applications the "right" third argument is 0444 or 0600 or 0400, but those are less common.  For a few (e.g., the last stage of compilation) the "right" third argument is even 0777.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the mode to [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open). Then it will set the permissions too. `open` is a variable argument function and you can pass more arguments to it

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
```

Do something like

```
open(LOCKFILE, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,
S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

Check the various permission bits [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html#Permission-Bits)